VScode C++ debugerの不具合？ ./csu/../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.hが読み込めません
Using C++ and WSL in VS Codeを参照しつつC++のcompile, debugをやっています。
Run helloworld.cppの項目まで進んだんですが、手元の環境で試してみると、以下のような不具合？が発生します。

エディタ右上のデバッグボタン（もしくはアクティブバーの「デバッグと実行」）からデバッグを開始
main関数のreturnをstep overすると、新しくタブが開いて以下の表示が出る


libc_start_call_main.h

ソース './csu/../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h' を読み込めませんでした: 'SourceRequest' not supported.。

該当
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> msg{"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};

    for (const string &word : msg)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

環境

Windows 11
Ubuntu24-04 on WSL2


FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76511088/ で同一事象へのQAがありました。エラーメッセージは「main関数を抜けた後の処理に対応するソースコードが見つからない」を意味しますから、同メッセージは無視しても構わないものです。
